# SQL Get the first field corresponding to some specified information in a non-normalized table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, inner-join

I have a SQL table that I cannot change the structure of.

The table Employee_Team has 5 columns: TeamID, Employee1, Employee2, Employee3 and Employee4. The fields of columns Employee1, Employee2, Employee3 and Employee4 contain an EmployeeID. Each Employee ID has a City in the table Employee. It’s possible to have multiple employees on the same row of Employee_Team that are living in the same town. There will always be at least 1 employee that will live in the town I’m looking for.

[example http://www.atriasoft.com/table.png](http://www.atriasoft.com/table.png)

Example:

I want the first employee that lives in New York. In the case of TeamID 01, it will be Employee2 (I don’t want Employee 4 even though his city is New York) and for the case of TeamID 02, it will be Employee1 (I still don’t want the second employee that lives in New York).

I currently have a code that gives me every employee that lives in New York:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM Employee_Team
 INNER JOIN Employees
    ON Employees.EmployeeID = Employee_Team.Employee1 OR
       Employees.EmployeeID = Employee_Team.Employee2 OR
       Employees.EmployeeID = Employee_Team.Employee3 OR
       Employees.EmployeeID = Employee_Team.Employee4
 WHERE Employees.City = ‘New York’
```

What I am looking for is a code that takes only the first employee living in New York. 
Any hints will be much appreciated!

Comment: What flavor of SQL are you using SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL, or Postgre?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually *can* safely "change" the definition of your table, virtually, by using it as the basis of a view:

```
 CREATE VIEW NormalTeams (TeamID, EmployeeID, TeamMemberNumber) AS
     SELECT TeamID, Employee1, 1 FROM Employee_TEAM UNION ALL
     SELECT TeamID, Employee2, 2 FROM Employee_TEAM UNION ALL
     SELECT TeamID, Employee3, 3 FROM Employee_TEAM UNION ALL
     SELECT TeamID, Employee4, 4 FROM Employee_TEAM
```

Now, NormalTeams will let you SELECT the data the way you expect to be able to:

```
 SELECT TeamID, MIN(TeamMemberNumber)
    FROM NormalTeams T INNER JOIN Employees E ON T.EmployeeiD = E.EmployeeID
    WHERE E.City = 'New York'
    GROUP BY TeamID
```

will give you the first team member "number" for New York.

```
 SELECT TeamID, City, MIN(TeamMemberNumber)
    FROM NormalTeams T INNER JOIN Employees E ON T.EmployeeiD = E.EmployeeID
    GROUP BY TeamID, City
```

will give you the more general solution for every City / Team combination.

You can join these results back to NormalTeams to get the employee ID.

Comment: This looks to be the correct solution if you add a "group by teamid" to the second select statement.

Comment: Oops!  Of course, you are correct — I will update to reflect.

Comment: Great! I didn't think of using a View to Normalize the table. Thank  you very much!

Answer (score 1):

A CASE statement should be your friend here:

```
SELECT et.TeamID
      ,CASE WHEN e1.City = c.city THEN e1.EmployeeID
            WHEN e2.City = c.city THEN e2.EmployeeID
            WHEN e3.City = c.city THEN e3.EmployeeID
            WHEN e4.City = c.city THEN e4.EmployeeID
            ELSE NULL
       END AS first_in_city
FROM  (SELECT 'New York' AS city) c    -- to parametrize the city we look for 
      ,Employee_Team et
LEFT   JOIN Employees e1 ON e1.EmployeeID = et.Employee1
LEFT   JOIN Employees e2 ON e2.EmployeeID = et.Employee2
LEFT   JOIN Employees e3 ON e3.EmployeeID = et.Employee3
LEFT   JOIN Employees e4 ON e4.EmployeeID = et.Employee4
```

The thing, that made your query crumble is this: you have to join in the `Employees` table four times, not just one time. Like it would be four different tables.
I chose LEFT JOIN, so we don't lose any rows if referential integrity should not be guaranteed.

Comment: Is it safe -slash- idiomatic -slash- a good idea to mix a comma-style CROSS JOIN with ANSI-style LEFT JOINs?

Comment: @ruakh: A comma is just a `JOIN` without join condition (effectively a `CROSS JOIN`). And an explicit JOIN binds before comma. I added that bit after OP declared MySQL. In PostgreSQL / Oracle / SQL-Server I would prefer a `WITH` clause for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

I like unpivot to normalize the structure/table so you could use below CTE to replace with View so no definition change but run-time parameter given.

```
with team_cte(TeamID, EmployeeID, n)
as
(
    select TeamID, EmployeeID, row_number() over (partition by TeamID order by TeamID) as n
    from    
        (select TeamID, Employee1, Employee2, Employee3, Employee4 
         from Employee_Team) p
    UNPIVOT
    (   
        EmployeeID  
        FOR Employee in (Employee1, Employee2, Employee3, Employee4)
    ) AS unpvt
)
select TeamID, min(n) as FirstEmployeeID
from team_cte 
where EmployeeID in
(
    select EmployeeID from Employees where City = 'New York'
)
group by TeamID
```

Comment: @Hogan: though in fairness: the OP did not declare MySQL at first. The tag was added later on.